# How can I output javascript function the amount of times selected in a dropdown menu on webpage?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project: To make a random quote(sentence) generator.
I have a function which assembles quote and logs a quote to console between 1 and 5 times depending on the number selected in dropdown menu on html page.
This works fine. However, instead of console.log I need the quote(s) to display on webpage in the same way they do in the console.

I don't know how to do it.
I'm new to Javascript so my understanding is limited.

```
//HTML drop down 

<select name ="quote_num" id="quote_num" onclick="getNumber()">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<h2>The oracles of wisdom say:</h2>
     <button onclick="michael_quote()">Reveal</button>



//JavaScript 

getNumber();

var numbaValue

function getNumber() {
var numbaElement = document.getElementById("quote_num");
numbaValue = numbaElement.options[numbaElement.selectedIndex].text;
console.log(numbaValue);
}


//Assembling the quote
function michael_quote() {

for (i = 0; i < numbaValue; i++) {

    var subjects = [...];
    var verbs = [...]; 
    var objects = [...];

    var random1 = subjects[Math.floor(Math.random() * subjects.length)];
    var random2 = verbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * verbs.length)];
    var random3 = objects[Math.floor(Math.random() * objects.length)];

    console.log(random1 + " " + random2 + " " + random3);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can grab your `h2` using `document.querySelector` and change it's textContent to the randomQuotes generated.

`document.querySelector('h2').textContent =`${random1} ${random2} ${random3}`;`

Comment: A note, this isn't jquery. It's regular javascript. You can find out more [here on the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Thanks Gustavo, my mistake. Cheers for the link, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 1):

You could do somethinglike this:

- Create a new HTML element with id `revealed_text`
- Create a variable `var text_to_reveal;` outside the `michael_quote()` function.
- Inside the function you initialize `text_to_reveal` with  an empty string `""`
- After the console log(or instead of it) you do `text_to_reveal += (random1 + " " + random2 + " " + random3 + "<br>");`
- After the loop, you do: `document.getElementById("revealed_text").innerHTML = text_to_reveal;` wich puts your saved text into the HTML element with id `revealed_text` that we created earlier.
- DONE

```js
getNumber();

var numbaValue

function getNumber() {
  var numbaElement = document.getElementById("quote_num");
  numbaValue = numbaElement.options[numbaElement.selectedIndex].text;
  //console.log(numbaValue);
}


var text_to_reveal;
//Assembling the quote
function michael_quote() {
  text_to_reveal = "";

  for (i = 0; i < numbaValue; i++) {

    var subjects = ["Tree", "House"];
    var verbs = ["go", "dive"];
    var objects = ["aaaa", "bbbb"];

    var random1 = subjects[Math.floor(Math.random() * subjects.length)];
    var random2 = verbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * verbs.length)];
    var random3 = objects[Math.floor(Math.random() * objects.length)];

    //console.log(random1 + " " + random2 + " " + random3);
    text_to_reveal += (random1 + " " + random2 + " " + random3 + "<br>");
  }
  
  document.getElementById("revealed_text").innerHTML = text_to_reveal;
}
```

```html
<select name="quote_num" id="quote_num" onclick="getNumber()">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<h2>The oracles of wisdom say:</h2>
<button onclick="michael_quote()">Reveal</button>

<div id="revealed_text"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!
That worked like a charm!
Really easy to follow!